# Binding ComboBox in Gridview Within Listview WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, data-binding

I have a Grid view in a Listview , all the other text Boxes gets bound without any problem but the combobox doesn't , ihave only two values possible for the combobox ( Yes / No ) and it should display it accordingly on databound.

XAML :

```
 <ComboBox  Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="tbJobDesttcrjiption" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ExpCertificate, Mode=TwoWay}" 
            SelectedIndex="0" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding}">                                                                                                            
            <System:String>Yes</System:String >                                                                                                                   
            <System:String>No</System:String>                                                                                                        
 </ComboBox>
```

Code Behind :

```
 cmd = new SqlCommand("getrelatedexperience", sqlconn.con);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", empid);
                        SqlDataAdapter daexp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataTable dtexp = new DataTable();
                        int kexp = daexp.Fill(dtexp);
                        commonDB = dtexp;
                        if (kexp > 0)
                        {
                            gvWExgp.ItemsSource = dtexp.DefaultView;
                        }
```

please give me solution for this , i have searched a lot no where i got a right solution.

Comment: What data type does {Binding Path=ExpCertificate} return? For the Combobox to recognize the SelectedItem the given value actually has to be present in the ItemsSource collection. So if you add "Yes" to the combobox ItemsSource and set the SelectedItem to true (boolean) it will not work! (btw. why are you setting the ItemsSource via Binding and on the same time adding elements as inlines?)

Comment: Since you specify items manually you can remove `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` and assuming your `ExpCertificate` is of a `string` type your code works

Comment: Like @dkozl said, you cannot use both ItemsSource, and manually specify the items. Choose one.